# random forest in python: final probabilities in classification problems

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, probability, random-forest

In classification problems  a RF classifier give the final response according to majority voting, e.g. yes or not about an event.

On the other hand I can see also a vector with the final probabilities of the event, e.g. 0,83. how this probability is calculated if I have 1000 estimators, is the mean of 1000 probabilities, from each tree?

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 4, min_samples_split=2, n_estimators = 200, random_state = 1) 
clf.fit(train[columns], train["churn"]) 
predictions = clf.predict(test[columns]) 
predicted_probs = clf.predict_proba(test[columns]) 
print(predicted_probs) 
test = pd.concat([test, pd.DataFrame(predicted_probs, columns=['Col_0', 'Col_1'])], axis=1)
```

Comment: Please post your code here. So we see your data structures and the problematic bits...

Answer (score 5):

> is the mean of 1000 probabilities, from each tree?

Yes, it is.

---

The vector shows the average probability of each selected class across all the trees. The final voting in Scikit RF classification selects the class with the highest mean probability for a given input for all trees.

So if for a dual class dataset, C1 and C2 have probabilities 0.3, 0.7 and 0.5, 0.5 across trees labeled 1 and 2 respectively for a given sample/input. C1 has an average probability of 0.4 while C2 an avg. of 0.6.

C2 is the selected class for that input as it has the highest mean probability across both trees.

---

You can also take a look at the source for the [`predict`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/412996f/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L514) method of `ForestClassifiers`. From the [`__doc__`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/412996f/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L517) of the method:

> The predicted class of an input sample is a vote by the trees in
>   the forest, weighted by their probability estimates. That is,
>   the predicted class is the one with highest mean probability
>   estimate across the trees.

Summarily, it's a type of majority voting where voting weights are not class frequencies across trees but mean values across trees.